# How to change the `TextFormField`'s `textScaleFactor` value?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

How to change `TextFormField`'s `textScaleFactor` like on text widget below?

```dart
Text(
  '...',
  textScaleFactor: 1,
),
```

Comment: Do you want to increase the font size of the text in TextFormField?

Comment: yes .  @FutureJJ

Comment: My answer below might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the way :)

## 1. A Simple Solution

```dart
final double scaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;

TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16 / scaleFactor,
  ),
),
```

There is also a sort of shortcut for this: `MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)`.

## 2. An Alternative (Better?)

You could also do something like changing the `MediaQuery` subcontext for the widget itself:

```dart
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
    textScaleFactor: 2 * MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context),
  ),
  child: TextFormField(...),
),
```